Web page scrolling past bottom of page on iPad
EDIT: While he hasn't given me anything solid, the client says he thinks his iPad is running iOS 13. I've had this tested on 5 different iPads ranging from iOS 15-17. Is 13 still an expected iOS to accommodate these days?

I am building a site in Angular (not sure it's relevant, but figured I'd mention it in case it is) and my client has shown me via video that when he scrolls to the bottom of the page on his iPad, it keeps going for at least a full screen's worth past the footer until he's looking at a solid screen of background color. I had him go to another site of mine also in Angular and it did the same thing. It didn't happen on some other public sites so that's why I'm wondering if Angular is relevant.
This doesn't happen on my PC and I've tested it on 3 different iPads (I'm still trying to get out of him which version he has so I don't have that info quite yet) and it works fine everywhere I've seen. I get the little iOS bounce at the bottom, but not this excessive scroll.
His site is still in development, but he saw it on the following live site of mine:
https://www.grandmascookieshoppe.com
I've looked around but haven't really found anyone detailing this exact issue.
Thank you.
Does this sound familiar to anyone

I don't see this on iPad (5th gen) IOS 16.7.10. I do see that 'Back to the top' gets revealed just at the end on overscroll and then immediately covered.
